# Array object offset to make a trapezium like shape

Tags: modifiers

i'm trying to make a set of diamonds 7 diamond wide and 21 diamond long, with a slight offset so that the line grows longer (but only length, not number of items) the more you go down the seven colums of 21 dimonds.

Any idea how i might do that ?

So far, i tried with a first array of 21 down Y, then a second array of 7, along X, which makes a nice rectangle...

[image]

but I can't seem to make the offset bigger and keep it symmetrical...

help ?

Comment: thanks for the correction

Comment: applied a scale I had made previously. Might do it for me, not sure yet...

Comment: Sorry for delay.. Do you want all the diamonds to be the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want all your diamonds the same size, a simple approach would be to use Vertex Instancing, one way or another.

**More Destructive:**

1. Create a plane, scaled in Edit Mode to your 1x3 dimensions
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *> Edge menu > Subdivide* the horizontal edges with 5 cuts, and the vertical edges with 19 cuts
3. In the plane's *Object* tab > *Instancing* panel, set instancing to Vertices..
4. .. and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> parent your gem to the plane.

You should now have a gem at every vertex.

5. You can now give the plane a *Simple Deform > Taper* modifier, down its long axis.
6. You can <kbd>X</kbd> *Delete > Only Faces* the plane, leaving you with a non-rendering wireframe.

**Less Destructive:**

1. Instead of using a plane, Create a *Single Vertex* at the origin.
   You may have to enable the shipped  *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* add-on, (or just borrow a vertex from another object)
2. Give it Constant-Offset *Array* modifier, in X, count 4, and another in Y, count 21
3. Give it a *Mirror* modifier across X, ensuring 'Merge' is checked.

The rest is as above, using Vertex Instancing, and a *Taper* modifier.

[image]

The second method leaves your arrays live, so you can change the count/spacing at a later stage, if you want to, but single verts can be a bit more fiddly to work with in the viewport.

If you needed your gems to get bigger towards the bottom, you could consider a particle-system emitted by vertex instead, and use a gradient texture to control their size.

Comment: cheers Robin, i also asked on the blender artist forum. They had a similar solution.
I ended up making multiple arrays with object offsets and a mirror modifier to make the shape, which was this:

Comment: https://pixeldrain.com/u/XZLzzP9q

https://blenderartists.org/t/array-object-offset-to-make-a-trapezium-like-shape/1277560?u=bondareingal_baboon

Comment: and as it turns out, the diamonds needed to get bigger the more you went down.

Comment: @titheringuelly_tarentulla I like your solution! It's non-destructive without the faff of particles. Good way to go.